# Flipping a three-sided coin

Tags: statistics

I have two related question on population statistics.  I'm not a statistician, but would appreciate pointers to learn more.

I have a process that results from flipping a three sided coin (results: A, B, C) and I compute the statistic `t=(A-C)/(A+B+C)`.  In my problem, I have a set that randomly divides itself into sets X and Y, maybe uniformly, maybe not.  I compute t for X and Y.  I want to know whether the difference I observe in those two t values is likely due to chance or not.

Now if this were a simple binomial distribution (i.e., I'm just counting who ends up in X or Y), I'd know what to do: I compute `n=|X|+|Y|`, `σ=sqrt(np(1-p))` (and I assume my `p=.5`), and then I compare to the normal distribution.  So, for example, if I observed `|X|=45` and `|Y|=55`, I'd say `σ=5` and so I expect to have this variation from the mean `μ=50` by chance 68.27% of the time.  Alternately, I expect greater deviation from the mean 31.73% of the time.

There's an intermediate problem, which also interests me and which I think may help me understand the main problem, where I measure some property of members of A and B.  Let's say 25% in A measure positive and 66% in B measure positive.  (A and B aren't the same cardinality -- the selection process isn't uniform.)  I would like to know if I expect this difference by chance.

As a first draft, I computed `t` as though it were measuring coin flips, but I'm pretty sure that's not actually right.

Any pointers on what the correct way to model this is?

Answer (score 0):

**First problem** 
For the three-sided coin problem, have a look at the multinomial distribution. It's the distribution to use for a "binomial" problem with more then 2 outcomes.

Here is the example from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution):

*Suppose that in a three-way election for a large country, candidate A received 20% of the votes, candidate B received 30% of the votes, and candidate C received 50% of the votes. If six voters are selected randomly, what is the probability that there will be exactly one supporter for candidate A, two supporters for candidate B and three supporters for candidate C in the sample?*

*Note: Since we’re assuming that the voting population is large, it is reasonable and permissible to think of the probabilities as unchanging once a voter is selected for the sample. Technically speaking this is sampling without replacement, so the correct distribution is the multivariate hypergeometric distribution, but the distributions converge as the population grows large.*

[image: formula for multinomial example]

**Second problem**
The second problem seems to be a problem for cross-tabs. Then use the "Chi-squared test for association" to test whether there is a significant association between your variables. And use the "standardized residuals" of your cross-tab to identify which of the assiciations is more likely to occur and which is less likely.